# What's the best way to implement AJAX "sliders"?

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, user-interface, cross-browser, user-experience

I'm working on a website that lists many things for sale, like gumtree or craigslist.

We're building a "slider" so users can easily refine their search by price. The user can:

- slide a control left or right to change the minimum/maximum price
- or click separate up/down arrows for both minimum and maximum
- or type a number in each box.

We currently have it working so that after changing any control, the listings are updated *only after the focus is changed*. But during testing we see that some users do not change the focus, or they only click on the browser scrollbar afterwards, which does not change the focus.

We can't have the listings update too quickly, as they will appear to 'jump around', and we also want to keep the HTTP requests to a minimum, for obvious reasons.

What are some examples of other websites who have solved this problem well?

What is the best way to implement this, in terms of best user experience and least requests sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly jQueryUI, but something similar in ExtJS: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/view/animated-dataview.html
ExtJS's event listeners offer a convenient `buffer` attribute for that very purpose. In this particular example, it's 70ms so you don't see much of an effect.

Not sure about jQuery UI, but it should not be hard to implement. This is how it works:

Instead of reacting to the blur event, you should listen to mousemove, keydown, klick, mousewheel etc.

- When user changes filter:

  ```
   if (listing.timer) { window.clearTimeout(listing.timer); }
   listing.timer = window.setTimeout(eventHandler, buffer);
  ```
- when listing is reloaded / destroyed or some other filter is applied:

  ```
  window.clearTimeout(listing.timer);
  ```
- eventHandler looks something like

  ```
  function eventHandler() {
    window.clearTimeout(listing.timer);
    delete listing.timer;
    // cancel pending requests if present...
    sendRequest(getFilterValues(), ...);
  }
  ```